# How to pass the Datetime value as parameter to a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

In the table, I have a column called as `BillDate (Datetime)`. The datetime is stored in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` (Example: `2012-01-01 00:00:00.000`). Now I want to retrieve the values between the range of datetime values. When I used query as the following I could not get the result:

```
SELECT * FROM RequestHeader
WHERE 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR, RH.BillDate ,105) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, @FromDate,105) 
  AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ToDate , 105)
```

---

```
@FromDate is passed as : '2012-01-01'
@ToDate is passed as : '2012-01-01'
```

Comment: what happens if you do not use the convert on the table column and the parameters?

Comment: "The Datetime is stored in the format YYYY-MM-DD" - no, it isn't. It is stored as a `DateTime`, whatever the internal representation of that is. Don't confuse formatting with storage.

Comment: Why are you passing in string parameters instead of `DateTime`?

Comment: Thank you. It does works well if i remove convert function. But what about when  the datetime is stored in the column as '2012-01-01 08:09:00.000'?

Comment: If you do any conversion of `DateTime` to string format, then you should **always** use the ISO-8601 format which is the only format guaranteed to work for all regional/language/dateformat settings on SQL Server. That format is either `YYYYMMDD` (**without** any dashes), or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for date+time (with the dashes). Those are the `CONVERT` styles no. 112 or 126

Comment: `DateTime` in SQL Server is not stored in any **STRING FORMAT** - it's a `DateTime` and it's stored as 8 binary bytes. It has **NO FORMATTING** applied to it - **NONE**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM RequestHeader
WHERE 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR, RH.BillDate ,105) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(@FromDate AS DATETIME),105) 
  AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(@ToDate AS DATETIME), 105)
```

Unfortunately, using this method doesn't utilize indexes, so if you're hoping that you'll have  fast query execution in the event that your date columns are indexed, you won't feel it here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 121-format code intead of 105, like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM RequestHeader
WHERE 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR, RH.BillDate ,121) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, @FromDate,121) 
  AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ToDate , 121)
```

**BUT** if it stored as DATETIME type, you need not to use CONVERT, and optimizer can use indexes in this case:

```
SELECT * FROM RequestHeader
WHERE 
  RH.BillDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to address the issue is to pass datetime values as datetime values, not as strings. This would be easier both on the SQL server and on the readers of your stored procedure's source code.

Answer (score 1):

In your example @FromDate is the same as @ToDate. There are no values between two equivalent value. I'm going to assume you have those values as just an example so I'll try to answer anyway.

First I don't see the need to convert the BillDate to VARCHAR. If the parameters passed are also dates there is no reason to convert those either. If not it can be converteed.

I created a simple test to confirm my assumptions:

```
DECLARE @FromDate VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ToDate VARCHAR(50)

SET @FromDate = '2012-01-01'
SET @ToDate = '2012-01-05'


INSERT INTO RequestHeader (BillDate) VALUES('12/1/2011')
INSERT INTO RequestHeader (BillDate) VALUES('1/3/2012')
INSERT INTO RequestHeader (BillDate) VALUES('1/4/2012')
INSERT INTO RequestHeader (BillDate) VALUES('1/5/2012')

SELECT * FROM RequestHeader
WHERE
    BillDate BETWEEN CAST(@FromDate AS DateTime) AND CAST(@ToDate AS DateTime)
```

Results:

```
BillDate
2012-01-03 00:00:00.000
2012-01-04 00:00:00.000
2012-01-05 00:00:00.000

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it as simple as possible

```
SELECT * FROM RequestHeader
WHERE 
  BillDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

@FromDate and @ToDate are, of course, datetime variables, not varchars.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM RequestHeader
WHERE BillDate 
BETWEEN convert(Datetime,@FromDate,102) 
AND convert(Datetime,@ToDate,102)
```

Answer (score 0):

The title and the question address different concepts. The title mentions "stored procedure" and the question and answers are direct selects from a table.

Answer (score 0):

i have procedure:
i can call it like this,

```
 create procedure insert_log (
       @id int,
       @date datetime2,
       @in_time time,
       @out_time time)
       as
       begin
       insert into student_log values(@id,@date,@in_time,@out_time)
       end;


     declare @date datetime2=getdate(),
            @in_time time=convert(time,getdate()),
            @out_time time=dateadd(minute,90,convert(time,getdate()))
    
    exec insert_log
        @id=3,
        @date=@date,
        @in_time=@in_time,
        @out_time=@out_time;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).